Is it possible to make a custom wave profile or modify existing wave profiles to get a non-symmetrical waves?
I'm using Triangle waves in geometry nodes to deform the plane. Now, as you can see in photo, on both sides, the faces of each wave is equal/symmetric:

Mesh photo (in first photo Subdivision is disabled only to show the initial mesh here. I'm actually working while enabling it.):


What I want is something like this, where one side of wave has wider face, the other side is shorter:

I have no idea how to approach it even if it's possible. If it's not possible in geo nodes, I would try Shader nodes too, using waves and displacement.

We would need to know what is your geometry (mesh). Is there only 1 vertex per peak ?

@Lutzi I've updated it. Hope it helps.

Use a fraction of Z to displace X and Y:
(or maybe use the "saw" wave instead, this method works with both types, triangle and saw, but with different multiplication factors)


Thanks it worked. The good thing with Saw is, I get actually what I need without any math nodes by default. But it has those sharp edges like teeth. I don't know how to make waves smooth like Triangle.

@Vikas Maybe you could float-mix it with a sine wave, or blur it

@Vikas, this works with any wave, you can use sine and the exact same nodes.

@DanielMöller yeah I tried and it works. The issue with Saw is those teeth/jagged edges which I don't need. But that's a separate question I will try to solve.

I would use a similar setup than Daniel Möller, except with a Color Ramp so that we can tweak the wave profile. The idea is, using a Wave Texture as a basis and map it to a custom range.

Color Ramps having an interpolation mode (here Linear), you can play with it to get different results.
You could achieve a similar result with a Float Curve node instead of the Color Ramp, but I find it harder to tweak precisely.

This is a cool idea. I guess that using a float curve could bring very very flexible and intuitive results.

I tested it works fine.

@DanielMöller yes it's more flexible.
